# php - custom variable href value does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, url, customization

I am editing the code page of a wordpress post.

Now here is the full page code:

```
<?php

    add_action( 'init', 'create_recipes' );
    function create_recipes() {
        //$portfolio_translation = get_option(THEME_NAME_S.'_cp_portfolio_slug','portfolio');

        $labels = array(
            'name' => _x('Recipes', 'Recipe General Name', 'crunchpress'),
            'singular_name' => _x('Recipe Item', 'Recipe Singular Name', 'crunchpress'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Add New Event Name', 'crunchpress'),
            'add_new_item' => __('Add New Recipe', 'crunchpress'),
            'edit_item' => __('Edit Recipe', 'crunchpress'),
            'new_item' => __('New Recipe', 'crunchpress'),
            'view_item' => __('View Recipe', 'crunchpress'),
            'search_items' => __('Search Recipe', 'crunchpress'),
            'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found', 'crunchpress'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash', 'crunchpress'),
            'parent_item_colon' => ''
        );

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_icon' => CP_PATH_URL . '/framework/images/recipe-icon.png',
            'rewrite' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments'),
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'recipes', 'with_front' => false)
          ); 

        register_post_type( 'recipes' , $args);

        register_taxonomy(
            "recipe-category", array("recipes"), array(
                "hierarchical" => true,
                "label" => "Recipe Categories", 
                "singular_label" => "Recipe Categories", 
                "rewrite" => true));
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type('recipe-category', 'recipes');

        register_taxonomy(
            "recipe-tag", array("recipes"), array(
                "hierarchical" => false, 
                "label" => "Recipe Tag", 
                "singular_label" => "Recipe Tag", 
                "rewrite" => true));
        register_taxonomy_for_object_type('recipe-tag', 'recipes');

    }


    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_recipes_option');
    function add_recipes_option(){  

        add_meta_box('recipe-option', __('Recipes Options','crunchpress'), 'add_recipe_option_element',
            'recipes', 'normal', 'high');

    }
    function add_recipe_option_element(){
        $recipe_price = '';
        $recipe_social = '';
        $sidebars = '';
        $right_sidebar_recipe = '';
        $left_sidebar_recipe = '';
        $recipe_detail_xml = '';
        $select_chef = '';
        $recipe_url = '';


    foreach($_REQUEST as $keys=>$values){
        $$keys = $values;
    }
    global $post;

    $recipe_detail_xml = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'recipe_detail_xml', true);
    $ingredients_settings = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ingredients_settings', true);
    $nutrition_settings = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'nutrition_settings', true);

    if($recipe_detail_xml <> ''){

        $cp_recipe_xml = new DOMDocument ();
        $cp_recipe_xml->loadXML ( $recipe_detail_xml );
        $recipe_price = find_xml_value($cp_recipe_xml->documentElement,'recipe_price');
        $recipe_url = find_xml_value($cp_recipe_xml->documentElement,'recipe_url');
        $recipe_social = find_xml_value($cp_recipe_xml->documentElement,'recipe_social');
        $sidebars = find_xml_value($cp_recipe_xml->documentElement,'sidebars');
        $left_sidebar_recipe = find_xml_value($cp_recipe_xml->documentElement,'left_sidebar_recipe');
        $right_sidebar_recipe = find_xml_value($cp_recipe_xml->documentElement,'right_sidebar_recipe');
    }
    ?>
        <div class="event_options">
            <ul class="recipe_class top-bg">
                <li><h2>Recipe Options and Social Sharing</h2></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="recipe_class">
                <li class="panel-title">
                    <label for="recipe_social" > <?php _e('SOCIAL NETWORKING', 'crunchpress'); ?> </label>
                </li>   
                <li class="panel-input">
                    <label for="recipe_social"><div class="checkbox-switch <?php

                    echo ($recipe_social=='enable' || ($recipe_social=='' && empty($default)))? 'checkbox-switch-on': 'checkbox-switch-off'; 

                ?>"></div></label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="recipe_social" class="checkbox-switch" value="disable" checked>
                <input type="checkbox" name="recipe_social" id="recipe_social" class="checkbox-switch" value="enable" <?php 

                    echo ($recipe_social=='enable' || ($recipe_social=='' && empty($default)))? 'checked': ''; 

                ?>>
                </li>
                <li class="description"><p>Turn On/Off Social Sharing on Event Detail.</p></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <ul class="recipe_class">
                <li class="panel-title">
                    <label for="recipe_price" > <?php _e('RECIPE PRICE', 'crunchpress'); ?> </label>
                </li>               
                <li class="panel-input">
                    <input type="text" name="recipe_price" id="recipe_price" value="<?php if($recipe_price <> ''){echo $recipe_price;};?>" />
                </li>
                <li class="description"><p>Please enter your recipe price.</p></li>
            </ul>   
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!--david-->
            <ul class="recipe_class">
                <li class="panel-title">
                    <label for="recipe_url" > <?php _e('RECIPE URL', 'crunchpress'); ?> </label>
                </li>               
                <li class="panel-input">
                    <input type="text" name="recipe_url" id="recipe_url" value="<?php if($recipe_url <> ''){echo $recipe_url;};?>" />
                </li>
                <li class="description"><p>Please enter your url</p></li>
            </ul>   
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <!--david end-->
            <?php echo show_sidebar($sidebars,'right_sidebar_recipe','left_sidebar_recipe',$right_sidebar_recipe,$left_sidebar_recipe);?>
            <ul class="recipe_class">
                <li class="panel-title">
                    <label><?php _e('Add Ingredients', 'crunchpress'); ?></label>
                </li>
                <li class="panel-input">
                    <input type="text" id="add-more-ingre" value="type title here" rel="type title here">
                    <div id="add-more-ingre" class="add-more-ingre"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="description"><p>Add Ingredients for this recipe.</p></li>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <ul class="nut_table">
                    <li>
                        <div>SrNo</div>
                        <div>Name</div>
                        <div class="panel-delete-cc">&nbsp;</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul id="selected-ingre" class="selected-ingre nut_table_inner">
                    <li class="default-ingre-item" id="ingre-item">
                        <div class="ingre-item-counter"></div>
                        <div class="ingre-item-text"></div>
                        <div class="panel-delete-ingre"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="ingredients">
                    </li>
                <?php
                //Sidebar addition
                if($ingredients_settings <> ''){
                    $ingre_xml = new DOMDocument();
                    $ingre_xml->loadXML($ingredients_settings);
                    $counter = 0;
                    foreach( $ingre_xml->documentElement->childNodes as $ingre_name ){
                    $counter++;
                    ?>
                    <li class="ingre-item" id="ingre-item">
                        <div class="ingre-item-counter"><?php echo $counter;?></div>
                        <div class="ingre-item-text"><?php echo $ingre_name->nodeValue; ?></div>
                        <div class="panel-delete-ingre"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" id="ingredients" value="<?php echo $ingre_name->nodeValue; ?>">
                    </li>
                <?php }
                }
                ?>
                </ul>
            </ul>   
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <ul class="recipe_class">
                <li class="panel-title">
                    <label> <?php _e('Add Nutrition', 'crunchpress'); ?> </label>
                </li>
                <li class="panel-input">
                    <input type="text" id="add-more-nutrition" value="type title here" rel="type title here">
                    <div id="add-more-nutrition" class="add-more-nutrition"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="description"><p>Add Nutrition for this recipe.</p></li>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <ul class="nut_table">
                    <li>
                        <div>SrNo</div>
                        <div>Name</div>
                        <div class="panel-delete-cc">&nbsp;</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <br class="clear">
                <ul id="selected-nutrition" class="selected-nutrition nut_table_inner">
                    <li class="default-nutrition-item" id="nutrition-item">
                        <div class="nut-item-counter"></div>
                        <div class="nutrition-item-text"></div>
                        <div class="panel-delete-nutrition"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" id="nutrition">
                    </li>
                <?php
                //Sidebar addition
                if($nutrition_settings <> ''){
                    $ingre_xml = new DOMDocument();
                    $ingre_xml->loadXML($nutrition_settings);
                    $counter = 0;
                    foreach( $ingre_xml->documentElement->childNodes as $ingre_name ){
                    $counter++;
                    ?>
                    <li class="nutrition-item" id="nutrition-item">
                        <div class="nut-item-counter"><?php echo $counter;?></div>
                        <div class="nutrition-item-text"><?php echo $ingre_name->nodeValue; ?></div>
                        <div class="panel-delete-nutrition"></div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="nutrition[]" id="nutrition" value="<?php echo $ingre_name->nodeValue; ?>">
                    </li>
                <?php }
                }
                ?>
                </ul>
            </ul>           
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <ul class="recipe_class">
                <li class="panel-title">
                    <label for="select_chef"><?php _e('SELECT CHEF', 'crunchpress'); ?></label>
                </li>               
                <li class="panel-input">    
                    <div class="combobox">
                        <select name="select_chef" id="select_chef">
                        <option>-- Select Chef --</option>
                        <?php

                        foreach(get_title_list_array('teams') as $our_team){?>
                            <option <?php if($select_chef == $our_team->post_name){echo 'selected';}?> value="<?php echo $our_team->post_name;?>"><?php echo $our_team->post_title?></option>
                        <?php }?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="description"><p>Please select Chef of this recipe.</p></li>
            </ul>   
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <input type="hidden" name="nutrition_type" value="nutrition">           
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>  
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <?php }
    add_action('save_post','save_recipe_option_meta');
    function save_recipe_option_meta($post_id){

        $recipe_social = '';
        $sidebars = '';
        $right_sidebar_recpie = '';
        $left_sidebar_recpie = '';

        foreach($_REQUEST as $keys=>$values){
            $$keys = $values;
        }

        if(defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;

        if(isset($nutrition_type) AND $nutrition_type == 'nutrition'){

        $new_data = '<recipe_detail>';
        $new_data = $new_data . create_xml_tag('recipe_price',$recipe_price);
        $new_data = $new_data . create_xml_tag('recipe_url',$recipe_url);
        $new_data = $new_data . create_xml_tag('recipe_social',$recipe_social);
        $new_data = $new_data . create_xml_tag('sidebars',$sidebars);
        $new_data = $new_data . create_xml_tag('right_sidebar_recipe',$right_sidebar_recipe);
        $new_data = $new_data . create_xml_tag('left_sidebar_recipe',$left_sidebar_recipe);
        $new_data = $new_data . '</recipe_detail>';

        //Saving Sidebar and Social Sharing Settings as XML
        $old_data = get_post_meta($post_id, 'recipe_detail_xml',true);
        save_meta_data($post_id, $new_data, $old_data, 'recipe_detail_xml');

        $recipe_setting_xml = '<recipe_ingredients>';
        if(isset($_POST['ingredients'])){$ingredients = $_POST['ingredients'];
            foreach($ingredients as $keys=>$values){
                $recipe_setting_xml = $recipe_setting_xml . create_xml_tag('ingredients',$values);
            }
        }else{$ingredients = '';}
        $recipe_setting_xml = $recipe_setting_xml . '</recipe_ingredients>';

        //Saving Sidebar and Social Sharing Settings as XML
        $old_data_ingre = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ingredients_settings',true);
        save_meta_data($post_id, $recipe_setting_xml, $old_data_ingre, 'ingredients_settings');

        $nutrition_setting_xml = '<recipe_nutrition>';
        if(isset($_POST['nutrition'])){$nutrition = $_POST['nutrition'];
            foreach($nutrition as $keys=>$values){
                $nutrition_setting_xml = $nutrition_setting_xml . create_xml_tag('nutrition',$values);
            }
        }else{$nutrition = '';}
        $nutrition_setting_xml = $nutrition_setting_xml . '</recipe_nutrition>';

        //Saving Sidebar and Social Sharing Settings as XML
        $old_data_nut = get_post_meta($post_id, 'nutrition_settings',true);
        save_meta_data($post_id, $nutrition_setting_xml, $old_data_nut, 'nutrition_settings');

        }
    }



    //FRONT END RECIPE LAYOUT
    $recipe_div_size_num_class = array(
        "Full-Image" => array("index"=>"1", "class"=>"sixteen ", "size"=>array(300,110), "size2"=>array(300,110), "size3"=>array(300,110)),
        "Small-Thumbnail" => array("index"=>"2", "class"=>"sixteen", "size"=>array(445,175), "size2"=>array(445,175), "size3"=>array(445,175)));


    // Print Recipe item
    function print_recipe_item($item_xml){
    wp_reset_query();
        global $paged,$sidebar,$recipe_div_size_num_class,$post,$wp_query,$counter;?>
        <!--<script src="<?php echo CP_PATH_URL;?>/frontend/js/jquery-filterable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
    <?php
        if(empty($paged)){
            $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1; 
        }
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($item_xml);die;
        //print_r($event_div_size_num_class);
        //$item_type = find_xml_value($item_xml, 'recipe-thumbnail-type');
        $item_type = 'Full-Image';
        // get the item class and size from array
        $item_class = $recipe_div_size_num_class[$item_type]['class'];
        $item_index = $recipe_div_size_num_class[$item_type]['index'];
        $full_content = find_xml_value($item_xml, 'show-full-news-post');
        if( $sidebar == "no-sidebar" ){
            $item_size = $recipe_div_size_num_class[$item_type]['size'];
        }else if ( $sidebar == "left-sidebar" || $sidebar == "right-sidebar" ){
            $item_size = $recipe_div_size_num_class[$item_type]['size2'];
        }else{
            $item_size = $recipe_div_size_num_class[$item_type]['size3'];
        }


        // get the blog meta value      
        $header = find_xml_value($item_xml, 'header');
        $num_fetch = find_xml_value($item_xml, 'num-fetch');
        $num_excerpt = find_xml_value($item_xml, 'num-excerpt');



        $category = find_xml_value($item_xml, 'category');
        $show_filterable = find_xml_value($item_xml, 'show-filterable');
        $category_name = '';
        $category = ( $category == 'All' )? '': $category;
        if( !empty($category) ){
            $category_term = get_term_by( 'name', $category , 'recipe-category');
            $category = $category_term->term_id;
            $category_name = $category_term->name;
        }

    ?>
    <h2  class="heading"><?php echo $header;?></h2>
    <?php 
    //Filterable Recipe Script start
    if($show_filterable == 'Yes'){?>
    <script>
        jQuery(window).load(function() {
            var filter_container = jQuery('#portfolio-item-holder<?php echo $counter?>');

            filter_container.children().css('position','absolute'); 
            filter_container.masonry({
                singleMode: true,
                itemSelector: '.portfolio-item:not(.hide)',
                animate: true,
                animationOptions:{ duration: 800, queue: false }
            }); 
            jQuery(window).resize(function(){
                var temp_width =  filter_container.children().filter(':first').width() + 20;
                filter_container.masonry({
                    columnWidth: temp_width,
                    singleMode: true,
                    itemSelector: '.portfolio-item:not(.hide)',
                    animate: true,
                    animationOptions:{ duration: 800, queue: false }
                });     
            }); 
            jQuery('ul#portfolio-item-filter<?php echo $counter?> a').click(function(e){    

                jQuery(this).addClass("active");
                jQuery(this).parents("li").siblings().children("a").removeClass("active");
                e.preventDefault();

                var select_filter = jQuery(this).attr('data-value');

                if( select_filter == "All" || jQuery(this).parent().index() == 0 ){     
                    filter_container.children().each(function(){
                        if( jQuery(this).hasClass('hide') ){
                            jQuery(this).removeClass('hide');
                            jQuery(this).fadeIn();
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    filter_container.children().not('.' + select_filter).each(function(){
                        if( !jQuery(this).hasClass('hide') ){
                            jQuery(this).addClass('hide');
                            jQuery(this).fadeOut();
                        }
                    });
                    filter_container.children('.' + select_filter).each(function(){
                        if( jQuery(this).hasClass('hide') ){
                            jQuery(this).removeClass('hide');
                            jQuery(this).fadeIn();
                        }
                    });
                }

                filter_container.masonry(); 

            });
        });
        </script>   
    <ul id="portfolio-item-filter<?php echo $counter?>" class="category-list">
        <li><a data-value="all" class="gdl-button active" href="#">All</a></li>
        <?php

        $categories = get_categories( array('child_of' => $category, 'taxonomy' => 'recipe-category', 'hide_empty' => 0) );
        //$categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'recipe-category' );                               
            if($categories <> ""){
                foreach($categories as $values){?>
                <li><a data-value="<?php echo $values->term_id;?>" class="gdl-button" href="#"><?php echo $values->name;?></a></li>                                
            <?php
                }
            }?>                            
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </ul>
    <?php }else{?>
        <h2 class="heading"><?php echo $category_name; ?></h2>
    <?php }?>                 
    <ul class="lightbox gallery_filterable" id="portfolio-item-holder<?php echo $counter?>">
    <?php
    $category = find_xml_value($item_xml, 'category');
    $category = ( $category == 'All' )? '': $category;
        if( !empty($category) ){
            $category_term = get_term_by( 'name', $category , 'recipe-category');
            $category = $category_term->slug;
        }
        if($show_filterable == 'Yes'){
        query_posts(array(
            'posts_per_page'            => -1,
            'post_type'                 => 'recipes',
            'recipe-category'           => $category,
            'post_status'               => 'publish',
            'order'                     => 'ASC',
            ));
        }else{
        query_posts(array(
            'posts_per_page'            => $num_fetch,
            'paged'                     => $paged,
            'post_type'                 => 'recipes',
            'recipe-category'           => $category,
            'post_status'               => 'publish',
            'order'                     => 'ASC',
            ));
        }
        while( have_posts() ){
        global $post;
        the_post(); ?>
                <li class="all portfolio-item item alpha
                    <?php
                    $categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'recipe-category' );
                        if($categories <> ''){
                            foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
                                echo $category->term_id." ";
                            }
                        }
                    ?>">
                    <h3 class="heading">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>">
                            <?php 
                            echo substr($post->post_title, 0, 20);
                            if ( strlen($post->post_title) > 20 ) echo "...";
                            ?>
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink();?>" class="caption">                                         
                        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $item_size);?> 
                        <span class="hover-effect big zoom"></span>
                    </a>
                    <!--david-->
                    <article class="menu-det">
                        <p><?php echo strip_tags(mb_substr(get_the_content(),0,$num_excerpt));?> <a class="c-link" href="<?php echo $recipe_url;?>"><?php _e('Read More...', 'crunchpress'); ?></a></p>
                    </article>                                                          
                </li>
    <?php }//End While?>
    </ul> 
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php
        if( find_xml_value($item_xml, "pagination") == "Yes" AND $show_filterable == 'No'){ 
            pagination();
        }   


     }  

?>
```

Now, at the bottom of this page above, you will see a readmore link with the following content:

```
<article class="menu-det">
    <p><?php echo strip_tags(mb_substr(get_the_content(),0,$num_excerpt));?> <a class="c-link" href="<?php echo $recipe_url;?>"><?php _e('Read M...', 'crunchpress'); ?></a></p>
</article>
```

Now the part giving me issues, is this one:

```
<?php echo $recipe_url;?>
```

So I basically only registered a new variable: **$recipe_url;**, and I replaced the original link href value of:

```
href="<?php echo get_permalink()?>"
```

with my new variable:

```
href="<?php echo $recipe_url;?>"
```

Now the url is empty on the webpage, even though a value is set. I even used some of the original variables included in the theme:

```
href="<?php echo $recipe_price;?>"
```

but it also does not populate a any url or href value..

Why is this? Am I calling it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: "Now the url is empty on the webpage, even though a value is set." How are you guessing it is indeed set? Also please isolate the problem part wjen having trouble with some piece of code instead of walldumping everything unrelated in your question.

Comment: You can use `var_dump($variable);` to see the type and content of `$variable`.

Comment: problem is, that when i call the variable using javascript alert, the popup window says that the variable value is 'undefined'. Why is it not set? Something tells me I am not calling it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to add a comment to the question, but you don't appear to have added a closing brace to the `add_recipe_option_element()` method either.

Comment: thanks, but I checked. the closing bracket is further down, so that is not a mistake.